# UITableView losing record after coming back from edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, master-detail, reloaddata

to study core data I have created a master detail tableview, with Clients and Projects. 
Master view shows clients and detail view shows the projects related to a specific client. 
There is also an editing mode, in which you can edit the client or project name you've entered.

my problem begins when I am in editing mode in the project screen. When I select a record, it will go to a view where you can adjust the project name. When I go back to the project view, my record that I just edited is gone.

I am not able to upload pictures yet, so I will try to clarify like this:

Projects:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

click "3" and change it to "3. three"
when back in the projects view you will see:

- 1
- 2
- 4
- 5

This works for al records that are selected.

This does not happen in het master view. I have compared both file again and again, but there are no differences. (Only difference is that in Master view I will load al record using -(NSArray *)allClients method and in detail I load all records using an -(NSArray *)relatedProjects:(Client *)client method

In the project view controller I have this, and it is getting called (I've checked)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

So hopefully someone can give me some pointers.
Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to post more code for people to see your problem better. Try NSLogging the array after the edit and see the elements in it. Does the element you edit disappear from the array too?

Comment: Hi, I didn't think of that, just checked and it is also disapearing from the NSArray. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Then there must be a mistake on the edit process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. While passing project data to the edit screen, I forgot to pass the client data, so each time I edited a record, client became null and disapeared, since there was no relationship any more between client en project.